# Javascript & become &amp;

Tags: javascript, html

I have some javascript in a div to make it move from an iframe to the main page. It works fine but when I use & like this:

```
function JS_onMouseOverBG(e, i_bg) {
  if( (block == 0)&&(i_bg != selected) ) {
    e.style.cursor = 'pointer' ;
  } else {
    e.style.cursor = '' ;
  }
}
```

Then `&` becomes `&amp;` and I have this firefox error:

```
Erreur : missing ) after condition
Fichier Source : http://192.168.0.20/lb/?p=467&w=prefs_bggen
Ligne : 905, Colonne : 22
Code Source :
  if( (block == 0)&amp;&amp;(i_bg != selected) ) {
```

I tried using the unicode `\u0026` of `&` but it does not work. I have an error of illegal character.

How can I do to use `&` in such a case ?

Edit:
I've found the solution, if someone looks for the same issue:

```
function JS_decode(str) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'); 
  div.innerHTML = str ;
  var decoded = div.firstChild.nodeValue; 
  return decoded ;
}
```

And I use this function for this DIV DIV_cover_js containing the Javascript code:

```
var eleJS = document.createElement("script") ;
eleJS.type = 'text/javascript' ;
eleJS.text = get('DIV_cover_js').innerHTML ;
eleJS.text = JS_decode(WP.eleJS.text) ;
eval(eleJS.text);
```

Comment: "Javascript in a div"? What?

Comment: Is the JavaScript enclosed in a `<script></script>` block? Or *just* 'inside a div'?

Comment: `JS_onMouseOverBG`? Have you been learning how to name functions from someone who used to work at Macromedia?

Comment: (I guess he's storing the script text in a `div` so that he can work around browser security restrictions and pull the script from an iframe into the "parent" document. But I want _him_ to explain that, before we get to explaining how silly it is.)

Comment: @Quentin, no I name then as I feel :/

Comment: @defacto: Do you name every Javascript function to start with "JS_"? Isn't it obvious that they're JS functions? Isn't this redundant and annoying? :)

Comment: @DavidThomas, yes it's working fine except when I use & in the Javascript. To make the javascript work, I do: `WP.eleJS.text = get('DIV_prefs_js').innerHTML ; eval(WP.eleJS.text);`

Comment: Just raising a personal opinion to those voting to close: how is this 'not a real question'? It might have obvious answers, it might seem silly, but the question itself seems genuine. And may (genuinely) be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: @David Thomas — Without the line of code contributed in the comment previous to yours the question is unanswerable without making some pretty big assumptions.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Yes, and php functions don't start with JS_...

Comment: @defacto: That's a small blessing, I suppose.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Because there is no reproducible testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Quoted from a comment by the OP):

> `WP.eleJS.text = get('DIV_prefs_js').innerHTML ; eval(WP.eleJS.text);`

If the original HTML includes `&&` then that is an [error](http://validator.w3.org) and the browser is correcting it.

You then get a serialisation of the DOM to HTML and try to treat some HTML as JavaScript.

If you really want to do this, then you should extract a `textNode` and use its `data` instead of `innerHTML`, however the approach is ugly, slow and hard to debug. You should have a proper JS function loaded via a `<script>` element in the first place.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Yes I know I should use <script> but there are some JavaScript variables generated with PHP and this PHP function can be called from the main page (index.php) AND from an iframe and is put in the main page. To put it to the main page from the iframe I use the eleJS main page variable. That's why ;-)

Comment: @defacto: I don't see a reasoning there. A reasoning includes an explanation as to why you can't do it a better way.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't go in a `<div>`. It goes in a `<script>`.